# when to use ajax jquery to get data from php file, Does it need to echo in php file to return data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when to use ajax jquery to get data from php file, **Does it need to echo** in php file to return data?   because I want to know if it has a case that not have to echo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $.post("test2.php", 
        {
          data1: $("#txt1").val(),
          data2: $("#txt2").val()
        },
            function(resut){
              $("#div1").html(resut);
            }
          );
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<div id="div1"></div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Load">

</body>
</html>
```

php file  test2.php

```
<?php

echo "You input : <u>".$_POST["data1"]."</u> and <u>".$_POST["data2"]."</u>";
?>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to echo the data in `test2.php` for it to display on the file where you made the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are supposed to echo/print the data in your server side (php). Only then the client side script can fetch the data.
You could also print the data in JSON formatted strings, and do the output formatting on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `echo json_encode($array);` and on server side
and on client side

```
<script>
   $.ajax({
       type : "GET",
       url : "job.php",
    }).done(function(msg) {
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
      alert(obj.name + " " + obj.last_name);
   });
</script>
```